# add devise:confirmable to 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, database-migration, devise-confirmable

Can someone give me an example of how to add devise to 2 different models with existing databases,i have 2 models, customer and vendor.If I just add :confirmable on both models and do the migration `rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise` will confirmable option be included in both models after I migrate the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you would have to create two separate migrations:

rails g migration add_devise_fields_to_customer

```
class AddDeviseFieldsToCustomer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Confirmable columns
    add_column :customers, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :customers, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :customers, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :customers, :unconfirmed_email, :string
  end
end
```

rails g migration add_devise_fields_to_vendor

```
class AddDeviseFieldsToVendor < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Confirmable columns
    add_column :vendors, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :vendors, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :vendors, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :vendors, :unconfirmed_email, :string
  end
end
```

That was just for Confirmable as that is the module you specified. If you wanted other devise modules (Trackable, DatabaseAuthenticatable etc) you would need to add those columns to the migration too.

You would also have to add the :confirmable (and any other features you wanted) to the models themselves.

Comment: hey thanks this helped me, can you tell me how can I trigger other mail send method to the customer table? Basically customisation Thank you.